# How to pick an specific object then push it into an existing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

```
api.get(`get-participant-reports/${this.userData.ind_id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.reportData = res.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.reportData.length; i++) {
          api.get(`get-not-eligible360/${this.reportData[i].id}`).then((res) => {
            this.reportData.push(res.data)
            console.log(this.reportData)
          });
        }
      });
```

I have `2 api` that I want to populate the same `variable` so I use `.push()` to insert the 2nd API call to the same `variable`.

This is what it looks like:

```
0:{
    "id": 30,
    "survey_template_name": "Big 5 Survey",
    "report_template_name": "5 Step Profile Report",
    "suborg_name": "Sandbox",
    "program_name": "MNET Testing",
    "iteration_name": "MNET2022 - Test July 2022",
}
1:{
    "id": 3280,
    "survey_template_name": "Big 5 Survey",
    "report_template_name": "5 Step Profile Report",
    "suborg_name": "Sandbox",
    "program_name": "MNET Testing",
    "iteration_name": "iteration-1a",
}
2:{
    "0": {
        "id": 30,
        "not_eligible": "1",
    }
}
3:{
    "0": {
        "id": 3280,
        "not_eligible": "1",
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is to get the `not_eligible` then `push` it into the existing `variable` that has the same `id` respectively. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have response data as array of object for both and need to add key `not_eligible` in first response data based on id of first response data so i have update code it should work for you.

```
    api.get(`get-participant-reports/${this.userData.ind_id}`)
          .then((res) => {
            this.reportData = res.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.reportData.length; i++) {
              api.get(`get-not-eligible360/${this.reportData[i].id}`).then((res) => {
                this.reportData.forEach(reportItem => {
                const existData = res.data.find(resItem => resItem.id === reportItem.id);
                  if (existData) {
                    reportItem.not_eligible = existData.not_eligible
                   }
                });
                console.log(this.reportData)
              });
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and if found set object property:

```
api.get(`get-participant-reports/${this.userData.ind_id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.reportData = res.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.reportData.length; i++) {
          api.get(`get-not-eligible360/${this.reportData[i].id}`).then((res) => {
            let idx = this.reportData.findIndex(i => i.id == res['0'].id)
            if(idx > -1) this.reportData[idx].not_eligible = res['0'].not_eligible
          });
        }
      });
```